# getModifierState() returned as an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, runtime-error

I am trying to debug a function using Firebug, for the JavaScript [`getModifierState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Methods) method seems to be not working. Here is the beginning of the function:

```
function kbdEq () {
  $(document).on ('keypress', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    debugger;
    var x = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
// etc.
```

Jumping into Firebug is straightforward, but trying to test

```
e.getModifierState('Alt')
```

(or any other keyboard event as a parameter, with or without quotes) results in this message from Firebug:

> e.getModifierState is not a function

I am using Firefox 44.0.2.

What mistake am I (presumably) making here?

Answer (score 16):

As you are using jQuery, note that the [event parameter (`e` in your case) is a jQuery specific object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) wrapping the actual event object.

To access the original event it has a property `originalEvent`. So, to access the modifier state you have to write this:

```
e.originalEvent.getModifierState("Alt");
```

Note that the jQuery event object has some simpler way to check whether the <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Meta</kbd> key is pressed. This can be done via `e.altKey`, `e.ctrlKey`, `e.shiftKey` and `e.metaKey`, respectively.

Comment: That is quite right, thank you. 1) getStateModifier is much more powerful than e.altKey, etc., for it can be passed a variable. 2) From reading jQuery documentation about the event objet or from reading jQuery in action, I could not have figured out the correct syntax (e.originalEvent.getModifierState…) Where did you find it? Better sources is even better than getting the right answer here !

Comment: Addendum: from jQuery, the right thing to do would be then to redeclare e as e.originalEvent at the beginning of a function that relies on events.

Comment: I simply logged the `e` object to the console and had a look at its properties within the [*DOM* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/DOM_Panel). When I saw `originalEvent`, it was clear to me that this is the "real" one. It is also mentioned within the jQuery documentation under *OtherProperties*, though I agree the description could be better. What you forgot to mention is that `getModifierState()` is [part of the `KeyboardEvent` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Methods). Therefore I've linked it in your question now.

Comment: That is all very good. You seem to have been downvoted for editing this post. Very strange…

Comment: I only see an upvote but no downvote. Maybe someone removed his vote again. But feel free to upvote and/or accept this answer if it helped you to solve your problem.

Comment: Wow I would've NEVER found that, thank you, still helping people in 2020 : )